# What does "Default bound to column" SSMS Message means?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I executed a required query on SSMS 2008 during configuration of a SQL Server Policy Store for CA Single Sign-On and I got this message repeatedly:

```
Default bound to column.
```

What does it mean? Is anything I should be worried about? I didn't found that much related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is raised by `sp_bindefault` that binds a default created by `CREATE DEFAULT` to a column of a table. Whenever a row is added to a table with a default and data for the column with the default is not specified, the column is populated by the value of default. In short, nothing to worry about. It seems your required query is creating a set of new tables and adding default to some of the columns.

Comment: Yes, it does :) Thanks.